# Deprecated ASP.NET Core NuGet Packages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget

I'm currently using the following packages for some shared code:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures
```

They have now been deprecated, and I cannot find a single reference to the one that I should be replacing them with.

Any help would be great.

Comment: At least for `ViewFeatures`, it looks like it's built-in now, so you can just drop the package as part of a .NET 6 upgrade. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/915139/why-is-there-not-a-microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-viewfe. Could be the same for the others.

Comment: I believe the APIs are available "in-box" with newer versions of ASP.NET, like in .NET 6, .NET 7, .NET 8. So, if you're already targeting those versions of the .NET runtime, then you probably don't need those packages at all. If you're not using those runtimes, then that's your upgrade path.

Comment: generally asking third party stuff like library suggestion is a no go. however, have you read [this discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7420)?

Comment: @BagusTesa That's not **3rd** Party, though. That's basically infrastructure.

Comment: @Fildor yeah sure, last time asked about oraclejdk/openjdk was downvoted for that exact reason.

Comment: @BagusTesa I cannot say anything about your question because I haven't seen it. I get that opinions may vary on this and maybe the java community is handling this differently.

Comment: The [nuget official link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/#supportedframeworks-body-tab)  clearly tells us that this is the last version of this package. It currently supports up to .NET7 and does not support the use of higher versions of .Net.

Comment: So there should be no other solution, unless the version of .NET is upgraded, these packages are already built in the higher version of .NET SDK. The 2.2 version we mentioned in this question can also support .NET Framework, so whether you need to upgrade this project, you need to decide according to your needs.